# Where Does WinRAR extract files opened directly?

Tags: windows-vista, winrar

When I open a .docx file directly from a RAR archive using WinRAR, where does WinRAR extract the file? My OS is Vista. RAR version 3.9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winrar extracts the archives to

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user_name>\Local Settings\Temp (Windows XP)
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp (Windows Vista/7)
```

by default, but I don't recommend you to edit an extracted file in a temp folder. Instead, extract the file (for example, to desktop), edit and save it, and then update the archive with the new file.

P.S.: You can change Winrar's default temp directory from Winrar's Options > Settings > Paths tab.

Comment: if I open .docx named AAA, should it be in dir C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp with the same name and extension? And If I close WinRAR, then it deletes the temp file at the same second?

Comment: When I open a .docx I can't see any change in Temp dir.

Comment: Winrar uses a random name for the files it extracts to Temp folder. You should extract the file.docx (for example, to desktop), edit and save it, and then update the archive with the new file. Why do you insist on playing inside the Temp folder?

Comment: Well, I agree with Mepher! You have to use suggestion above.

Only to know and for emergency cases, when you open a document, execute setup etc. in Winrar, it generates a random directory, for example, WER01e5.dir00, in Windows temp folder by default (you can access it only writting %temp% in Explorer or in Run)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a your temp folder.
Should be something like `C:\Users\Some User\AppData\Local\Temp` if you're on Win7

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case the AppData folder was hidden. You can change hidden folders visibility from Control Panel → Folder Options → View → Advanced Options.

Answer (score 0):

It temporary files go in:

```
C/Users/<your username>/AppData/Local/Temp
```

The temporary files are extracted in a folder with a similar name: `Rar$DRa0.135`

Just open the folder and if you find the same files you were extracting, those are the ones.